# I want to find the position of repeated values in a list, and then use them as a condition to evaluate afunction

Tags: list-manipulation, mechanism

My program recieves four inputs representing linkages in a 4-bars mechanism:

Then it has to find the Largest and Smallest linkage and evaluate its sum against the other two:

L+S<P+Q

where L is the largest linkage
S is the smallest
P & Q are the others.

My problem arises when there are two repeated linkages which happen to be max or min.

I want my program to do this without specifying which is the longest. So far I had to manually type what value to use. please help me.

```
Subscript[L, 1] = 0.15;
Subscript[L, 2] = 0.05;
Subscript[L, 3] = 0.15;
Subscript[L, 4] = 0.1;
linkages = Table[Subscript[L, i], {i, 1, 4}];
min = Min[linkages];
max = Max[linkages];
lizq = min + max;
Print["Are values unique?"]
DuplicateFreeQ[linkages]
dupl = Tally[linkages];
Print["Is Grasshoff condition satisfied?"]
middlelinks = Complement[linkages, {max, min}];

If[DuplicateFreeQ[eslabones], lizq < Total[middlelinks], 
 max + min < Total[middlelinks] + dupl[[1, 1]]]
```

Comment: how about: `sorted = Sort[linkages]; Total@sorted[[{1, -1}]] < Total@sorted[[{2, 3}]]`?

Comment: .. or `Total@Differences[sorted, 2] < 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[grasshoffQ1, grasshoffQ2]

grasshoffQ1[lst : {a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Module[{sorted = Sort[lst]}, 
  Total@sorted[[{1, -1}]] < Total@sorted[[{2, 3}]]]

grasshoffQ2[lst : {a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Module[{sorted = Sort[lst]}, 
  Total@Differences[sorted, 2] < 0]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
lists = RandomInteger[10, {10, 4}];

Grid[Prepend[{"list", "Sort[list]", "minmax", "middlelinks", 
      "grasshoffQ1[list]", "grasshoffQ2[list]"}]@
  Table[{i, Sort@i, MinMax@i, Sort[i][[{2, 3}]], grasshoffQ1@i, grasshoffQ2@i},
      {i, lists}], 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]